# Are template literals supported inside forEach methods' nested console.log functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, foreach

I have a forEach method which returns a console.log() for each element in the Array.
If I place template literals in it, I get printed in the console:
[object HTMLLIElement] instead of the correct evaluation of the object `"<li class="sel">..."`

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#start");
let sel = container.querySelectorAll(".sel");

//The following works as it should:
   // sel.forEach((element, pos) => console.log( element,pos));
//This , however does not
sel.forEach((element, pos) => console.log( ` ${element} + ${pos} `)); //and prints " [object HTMLLIElement] + 0 "
```

```html
 <div id="start">
        <ul>
            <li class="sel">valoare 1</li>
            <li class="sel">valoare 2</li>
            <li class="sel">valoare 3</li>
            <li>valoare 4</li>
            <li class="sel">valoare 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: `console.log` (in the browser), treats HTMLElements specially and gives them the interactive menu. By converting them to a string with a template literal, you lose that ability. If you want to log the position as well, you could try `console.log(element, "+", pos)`.

Comment: "instead of the correct evaluation of the object" what does that mean? You are doing toString() on an object.

Comment: I had trouble in revising the edit to the question, because someone else also corrected it while I was trying to submit changes - where I said the correct evaluation that appears in the console "<li class="sel">..." ( when I run the code that works  sel.forEach((element, pos) => console.log( element,pos));

Comment: I don't think that my or @iota's answers are elitist. I think I've put together a pretty comprehensive answer with links to the relevant resources for you to fully understand what's happening and how to get what you want.

Comment: (what bugged me is that I hadn't finished modifying the question, after noticing some errors in the way it was formulated and the downvote immediately came... before I managed to even submit the modifications)

Comment: (and wasn't talking about the answers, but about the immediate downvote; maybe I'm too sensitive, but it's not the first time I've encountered this on this forum)

Answer (score 0):

The use of template literals force a [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) call on the `element` reference, which is returned as `[object HTMLLIElement]`.

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString):

> If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString()
> returns "**[object type]**", where type is the object type.

Without the template literal, you are leaving it up to the browser to render the value, which returns the implicit result of calling [`element.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) and returns the unparsed HTML of the element.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");
console.log(div);             // Implicit .valueOf() call
console.log(div.valueOf());   // Explicit .valueOf() call

const el = div;
console.log(`${div}`);        // Implicit .toString() call
console.log(div.toString());  // Explicit .toString() call
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

So, when using template literals, you need to understand that you are asking to log the string representation of the ***element itself*** and not ***some property*** of the element.

In your case, template literals are not needed because [the `forEach` arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) give you access to the data you might need through the [element node interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and calling [`element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) will return the entire element's HTML.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#start .sel").forEach(
  (element, pos) => {
    // The forEach element argument provides a reference to the
    // element instance being iterated. You can access anything
    // you need to using that element's API:
    console.log(element.nodeName, 
                element.className, 
                element.textContent, 
                element.outerHTML,
                pos);
   }
);
```

```html
<div id="start">
        <ul>
            <li class="sel">valoare 1</li>
            <li class="sel">valoare 2</li>
            <li class="sel">valoare 3</li>
            <li>valoare 4</li>
            <li class="sel">valoare 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate the element's `outerHTML`.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#start");
let sel = container.querySelectorAll(".sel");

sel.forEach((element, pos) => console.log( `${element.outerHTML} + ${pos} `));
```

```html
 <div id="start">
        <ul>
            <li class="sel">valoare 1</li>
            <li class="sel">valoare 2</li>
            <li class="sel">valoare 3</li>
            <li>valoare 4</li>
            <li class="sel">valoare 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```